# Maven cucumber.options argument usage in Teamcity

Tags: maven, selenium-webdriver, teamcity, cucumber-jvm

I have a test automation framework and I am able to run my tests from maven command line with the following without any error:

```
mvn clean test -Pdev -Dserver="remote" -Dbrowser="ie" -Dcucumber.options="--tags @test"
```

I try to integrate it to teamcity but there are some problem with the arguments.

My config in Build Step:Maven:

Goals: clean test

path to pom file: is correct

Additional maven Command Line Parameters:

```
-Pdev
-Dserver=remote
-Dbrowser=ie
"-Dcucumber.options=--tags @test"
```

When I start the job, the test has been started but never ends, just it runs continuously and the job is stucked.

Any idea why? I'm pretty sure, cucumber.options arguments syntax is wrong, but without quotes it doesn't work at all. Please note, locally everything is working fine, there is no any error in arguments/maven profile etc.

Thanks!

Comment: When you say the cucumber.options syntax is wrong, do you mean the fact that you're quoting the whole thing rather than just the value of the option? That's not necessarily wrong; it is possible to quote things this way on Windows.

Comment: Do you have access to the TC agent? Could you use Process Explorer to see whether `mvn` gets executed, and with what parameters? Could you consult the Maven logs? Also, I'm not an expert, but could the hanging be due to the different set-up of the server? For example, something to do with IE, the Internet options, the firewall? Do other such tests run for you? Can you simplify it any further, e.g. so that you don't need the cucumber options?

Comment: Thanks Guys, I cannot simplify it any further because the test customization is very important. I need to use tags. Unfortunately I cannot access to the logs... Regarding the quotes, I tried it without them, did not work, so I used this way, but the job cannot handle it because the whole tests suite runs in infinite loop.. That's why I guessed I made some mistake there.

Answer (score 1):

If your TeamCity instance is running on Windows, the below syntax for defining Cucumber Options in the Additional Maven Command Line Parameters should work:

```
"-Dcucumber.options= --tags @test"
```

[image: Example TeamCity Maven Job Configuration]

Not sure if it matters, but notice I have a space in between the `=` character and `--tags`